# Having a fixed Column while the other is scrollable inside an unordered list

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, tabbed

I am using a TabbedContent script that creates a large width div. This div in turn has several unordered lists in it, each list will correspond to a tab. The script then adjusts the width of the large div to fit the list in the area where it's showing content.

Right now, I cannot set a fixed div in it or an absolute div, for the scroll will no longer work. What I need is a 2 column setup, where the left column needs to stay fixed while the right column has text. Both need to be inside the list and I need to be able to replicate it on the other tabs.

Here's the .js I'm using to run the tab system:

```
    var TabbedContentSolutions = {
    init: function() {  
        $(".tab_thumb").click(function() {

            $(this).siblings().removeClass('active_thumb');
            $(this).addClass('active_thumb');

            var background = $(this).parent().find(".moving_bg2");

            $(background).stop().animate({
                left: $(this).position()['left']
            }, {
                duration: 0
            });

            TabbedContentSolutions.slideContent2($(this));

        });
    },

    slideContent2: function(obj) {

        var margin = $(obj).parent().parent().find(".slide_content2").width();
        margin = margin * ($(obj).prevAll().size() - 1);
        margin = margin * -1;

        $(obj).parent().parent().find(".tabslider2").stop().animate({
            marginLeft: margin + "px"
        }, {
            duration: 0
        });
    }
}


$(document).ready(function() {
    TabbedContentSolutions.init();
});
```

Here's the CSS that is controlling the .js and the divs:

```
    .tabbed_content2 {
    background-color: ##F7931E;
    width: 1000px;

}

.tabbed_content2 .slide_content2 {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 1000px;
}

.tabs2{
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    height: 32px;
    width: 670px;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
}

.tabs2 .tab_thumb{
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    margin-left: 9px;
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.tabslider2{
    width: 17000px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.tabslider2 ul {
    float: left;
    width: 980px;
    height: 323px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

#_solutions{
    width: 980px;
    height: 300px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.solutions_left{
    width: 273px;
    height: 330px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    float: left;
    }

.solutions_right{
    width: 670px;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    float: left;
}

.tabslider2 ul li {
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.active_thumb{
    opacity: .10;
}
```

And here is the basic div setup I'm using to make the tabs:

```
  <div id="_Content">
            <div id="_solutionsWrap">
                <div class='tabs2'>
                    <div class='moving_bg2'>
                    </div>
                    <span id="solucoes" class='tab_thumb' style="display:none">
                        asdasdasd
                    </span>
                                <div id="_solutions">
                    <div class='tabbed_content2'>
                        <div class='slide_content2'>
                            <div class='tabslider2'>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                    <div class="solutions_left">
                        <p></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="solutions_right">
                    <h1>solutions</h1>
                    <p></p>

                    <p></p>
                    </div>

                    </li>
                    </ul>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I know it sounds confusing, but there will be at least 17 different tabs, and each will need to have a non scrolling let bar to display an image.

Absolute positioning will simply not work, everytime you'd try to switch tabs, the div would remain inside the display area.

Fixed has the same problem.
I have no idea how to solve this problem, as I know little to no Javascript, much less jQuery.

Comment: create a live demo in jsfiddle.net that demonstrates the problem. Solutuon likely has nothing to do with script and is likely purely css related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I not sure about your tab system, but one from jquery-ui works fine -

http://jsfiddle.net/jg5CC/2/

html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <div class="image">img5</div>
        <p>aProin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <div class="image">img4</div>
        <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        <div class="image">img3</div>
        <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
        <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
    </div>
</div>
​
```

css:

```
.image {
 position: fixed;  
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background: lightgreen;  
 opacity: 0.7;    
}
p {
 height: 1000px;   
}​
```

js:

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs();
```

Comment: Your solution is nice, but based on what you posted, I made the left column entirely fixed, but simply added a margin to the right column to offset it rom behind the left one. Doesn't break the layout and keps everything OK. Thank you.